# confidence of detection in presence of poisson noise

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, noise

Say I have a detector that tells me if one or more events has occurred in a given time interval (and the length of this time interval is fixed, i.e., not decided by me). I am also able able to push a button that will cause an event to happen within that time interval with high (but unknown) probability if condition A is true. Condition A is either always true or never true. This detector also picks up events that occur naturally according to a Poisson process with an unknown and potential high lambda value.

If I take N pairs of measurements with this detector, one measurement pressing the button and one measurement without pressing it, and I get n1 and n2 detections respectively, how do I calculate the likelihood that condition A is true?

Seems like a typical problem, but in what I've be able to find so far, the detector is able to count events, not just say whether one or more happened.

Comment: What happens to the behavior when you press the button and the condition doesn't hold? Nothing?

Comment: Yes, same behavior as if button was not pressed (i.e., just noise)

Comment: Now that I think about it a little more, this is just estimating the probability of one event (noise) and also the probability of that event or a second event (detection) and calculating the confidence that the probability of the second event is non-zero.

Comment: OK, so do I understand the situation correctly: you have two iid Poisson r.v.s $X_1,X_2$ and another r.v. $Y$ independent of $X_1,X_2$. You measure $X_1$ and $X_2+Y$. Y is either Bernoulli(p) where $p$ is close to $1$ or else identically zero. You want to determine whether $Y$ is Bernoulli(p) or identically zero. Or is the situation worse because the detector can only tell whether *some* event has happened, but not provide a count?

Comment: The detector is binary, either no event occurred in the time interval or at least one event and possibly more occurred.

Comment: OK. So you have a Binomial($N,e^{-\lambda}$) and another Binomial($N,e^{-\lambda}$) plus either Bernoulli(p) or zero. Seems straightforward enough.

Comment: Do you have priors for the parameters ($p$ and $\lambda$ above)?

Comment: No. Not really.

Comment: Well, only that _p_ is close to 1 (maybe close enough to have _p_ as a prior) and I'm mostly concerned about when λ is fairly high (so the probability of noise triggering the detector is somewhat close to 1 as well).